# ProxMox VPS modprobe fuse not working

Tags: vps, samba, kernel, sshfs

I'm needing to mount a directory using sshfs, but for that to work I need fuse.

When I run modprobe fuse i'm getting this:

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-4-pve/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

After some research apparently its because that the ProxMox VPS host does not support fuse in the kernel. Is there anyway I can get around this? I really don't want to use Samba, is there any other way of mounting a remote directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not in the kernel (compiled in) and there is no loadable module available, then you are lost.

The only way to get this done is use a kernel with built-in fuse support or build your own kernel. But if that is possible depends on the environment you have.